# Unicodes in statuscode of HTTP-Response in Jetty

Tags: java, http, jetty, embedded-jetty

I want to send characters like `„` as status code. 
F.e.: `484 - User „me“  not found`

In my test-example i tried the following (i know that `setStatus(int,string)` is deprecated):

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "User „me“  not found");
```

What I get in the client is: `User ?me? not found`.

Is there a way to send those characters as statuscode in jetty? My research about this was unsuccessful..

I'm using jetty 9.4.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the behavior for non-ASCII characters is essentially undefined.

Furthermore, the reason phrase does not exist in HTTP/2, so I wouldn't build any functionality on it.

Comment: Also, since Servlet 2.1, the API [`HttpServletResponse.setStatus(int, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus-int-java.lang.String-) has been deprecated for similar reasons.